PPO clip AI issues
I have been trying to make a PPO clip AI using openai's pseudocode from a while ago however it is not very good. I am only trying a simple environment (cartpole) and the issue appears to be that after it runs for a little bit it develops a bias towards the move it originally takes meaning it moves in one direction more than the other.
I have tried changing the hyper parameters in many ways and it hasn't changed much so I believe there is a fundamental flaw in the code that is causing the issue, that or I missed something with the parameters.
My code is two files a main.py and a PPO_discrete.py:
main.py
import gymnasium as gym
from PPO_discrete import PPOAgent

def main():
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v1', render_mode="rgb_array")  # Create CartPole environment
    state_dim = 4  # Dimension of state space
    action_dim = 2  # Number of discrete actions in the action space

    # Initialize PPO agent
    agent = PPOAgent(state_dim, action_dim, env)
    
    agent.learn(20500, True)  # Train the agent
    print("Done training")

    env.close()  # Close the environment after training

    # Reopen the environment for testing
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v1', render_mode="human")

    for _ in range(1000):  # Test for 100 episodes
        obs, _ = env.reset(seed=49)
        done = False

        while not done:
            action, _ = agent.get_action(obs)  # Extract only the action
            next_obs, _, terminated, truncated, _ = env.step(action)  # Pass only action to step()
            obs = next_obs
            done = terminated or truncated

    env.close()  # Properly close the environment after testing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

PPO_discrete.py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

# Policy Network for Discrete Environments
class DiscretePolicyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim):
        super(DiscretePolicyNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(state_dim, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.logits = nn.Linear(64, action_dim)

    def forward(self, state):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        logits = self.logits(x)  # Output logits for each action
        return logits


class ValueNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim):
        super(ValueNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(state_dim, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 1)

    def forward(self, state):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        value = self.fc3(x)
        return value


# PPOAgent with implemented optimizer parameter values
class PPOAgent:
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, env):
        # Initialize policy and value networks
        self.policy_net = DiscretePolicyNetwork(state_dim, action_dim)
        self.value_net = ValueNetwork(state_dim)

        # Initialize optimizers with the specified parameter values
        self.policy_optimizer = optim.Adam(self.policy_net.parameters(), lr=0.0003, eps=1e-5)
        self.value_optimizer = optim.Adam(self.value_net.parameters(), lr=0.0003, eps=1e-5)

        # Manually set the optimizer state values
        for optimizer in [self.policy_optimizer, self.value_optimizer]:
            for state in optimizer.state.values():
                state['step'] = torch.tensor(1600.)
                state['exp_avg'] = torch.tensor([-0.0153])
                state['exp_avg_sq'] = torch.tensor([0.0024])

        # Environment and other hyperparameters
        self.env = env
        self.mean = np.zeros(env.observation_space.shape)
        self.std = np.ones(env.observation_space.shape)
        self.batch_size = 64
        self.epoch_count = 4
        self.gamma = 0.99  # Discount factor
        self.lambda_ = 0.95  # GAE parameter
        self.entropy_bonus = True
        self.epsilon = 0.2  # Clipping range
        self.beta = 0.01  # Entropy coefficient
        self.n_steps = 1024  # Number of steps per rollout


    def learn(self, k, frames):
        timesteps_perm = 0
        timesteps = 0
        states, actions, rewards, log_probs = [], [], [], []
        playing = True
        episode_rewards = []  # Track rewards per episode
        episode_reward = 0  # Track reward for the current episode

        while playing:
            obs, _ = self.env.reset(seed=49)
            done = False

            while not done:
                timesteps_perm += 1
                timesteps += 1
                action, log_prob = self.get_action(obs)

                next_obs, reward, terminated, truncated, _ = self.env.step(action)

                # Collect data
                states.append(obs)
                actions.append(action)
                rewards.append(reward)
                log_probs.append(log_prob)

                episode_reward += reward
                obs = next_obs
                done = terminated or truncated

                if done:
                    episode_rewards.append(episode_reward)
                    episode_reward = 0

                # Process batch if enough timesteps collected
                if timesteps >= self.n_steps:
                    timesteps = 0
                    self._process_batch(states, actions, rewards, log_probs)
                    avg_action = np.mean(actions)
                    states, actions, rewards, log_probs = [], [], [], []  # Reset batch

                    # Print stats after each batch
                    avg_reward = np.mean(episode_rewards[-10:]) if episode_rewards else 0
                    print(f"Batch Processed: Avg Reward (last 10 eps): {avg_reward:.2f}, Timesteps: {self.n_steps}, Total: {timesteps_perm}, Average action: {avg_action}")
                    episode_rewards = []

                if timesteps_perm >= k:  # Stop training after collecting enough states
                    playing = False

    def get_action(self, obs):
        state_tensor = torch.tensor(obs, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)
        logits = self.policy_net(state_tensor)
        distribution = torch.distributions.Categorical(logits=logits)
        action = distribution.sample()  # Get action as a tensor
        log_prob = distribution.log_prob(action)

        return action.item(), log_prob.detach()

    def _process_batch(self, states, actions, rewards, log_probs):
        rewards = (rewards - np.mean(rewards)) / (np.std(rewards) + 1e-8)
        states_tensor = torch.tensor(states, dtype=torch.float32)

        # Compute rewards-to-go (RTGs)
        rtgs = self._compute_rtgs(rewards)

        # Compute values from the value network
        values = self.value_net(states_tensor).squeeze(-1).detach()

        # Compute advantage estimates using GAE
        advantages = self._compute_advantage_estimates(rtgs, rewards, values)

        # Normalize advantages for stability
        advantages = (advantages - advantages.mean()) / (advantages.std() + 1e-8)

        self._update_policy(advantages, actions, log_probs, states)

        # Fit the value function to RTGs
        self._fit_value_function(rtgs, states_tensor)

    def _compute_rtgs(self, rewards):
        rtgs = []
        running_rtg = 0

        for r in reversed(rewards):
            running_rtg = r + self.gamma * running_rtg
            rtgs.insert(0, running_rtg)

        return torch.tensor(rtgs, dtype=torch.float32)

    def _compute_advantage_estimates(self, rtgs, rewards, values):
        advantages = torch.zeros_like(torch.tensor(rewards, dtype=torch.float32))

        gae = 0
        for t in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
            next_value = 0 if t == len(rewards) - 1 else values[t + 1]
            delta_t = rewards[t] + self.gamma * next_value - values[t]
            gae = delta_t + self.gamma * self.lambda_ * gae
            advantages[t] = gae

        return advantages

    def _update_policy(self, advantages, actions, log_probs, states):
        states_tensor = torch.tensor(states, dtype=torch.float32)
        actions_tensor = torch.tensor(actions, dtype=torch.int64)  # Actions are now integers
        old_log_probs_tensor = torch.tensor(log_probs, dtype=torch.float32)

        for _ in range(self.epoch_count):  # Use multiple epochs for stability
            logits = self.policy_net(states_tensor)
            distribution = torch.distributions.Categorical(logits=logits)
            new_log_probs = distribution.log_prob(actions_tensor)

            # Compute the probability ratio
            ratios = torch.exp(new_log_probs - old_log_probs_tensor)

            # Compute the surrogate objective
            surrogate_1 = ratios * advantages
            surrogate_2 = torch.clamp(ratios, 1 - self.epsilon, 1 + self.epsilon) * advantages
            clip_loss = torch.min(surrogate_1, surrogate_2).mean()

            # Add entropy bonus
            entropy_bonus = distribution.entropy().mean() if self.entropy_bonus else 0
            loss = -clip_loss - self.beta * entropy_bonus

            self.policy_optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.policy_net.parameters(), max_norm=0.5)
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.value_net.parameters(), max_norm=0.5)
            self.policy_optimizer.step()

    def _fit_value_function(self, rtgs, states_tensor, reps=2):
        rtgs = rtgs.detach()  # Detach the targets, they don't require gradients
        for _ in range(reps):
            pred_vals = self.value_net(states_tensor).squeeze(-1)
            mse_loss = torch.mean((rtgs - pred_vals) ** 2)

            self.value_optimizer.zero_grad()
            mse_loss.backward()
            self.value_optimizer.step()

